# Layer dense_66 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of `N folder(N ID)`, each `N ID folder` have `M folder` inside, and each M folder have 8 images inside it. I want to train the dataset with `2D-CNN`. My model contain `8 CNNs` each one take one of the M folder image, after ending the first folder of that ID, the model take the next folder with 8 images and each image goes to one of the 8 models and so on. finally I concatenate the output of the 8 models, but I faced a problem when I want to concatenate all dataset. How can I concatenate the output of the first 8 models, with the output of the second 8 models and so on till the dataset ended. my model design is as the follwing images:
[image]

my python code is as following:

```
model_out = []
input_list = []
model_list = []
for fold_Path in listing:
image_fold = os.listdir(ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path)
for file in image_fold:
    segments = os.listdir(ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path + "\\" + file)
    segments_list = []
    input_list = []
    output_list = []
    model_out = []
    for seg in segments:
        im = (ID_Paths + "\\" + fold_Path + "\\" + file + "\\" + seg)
        image = cv2.imread(im)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (60, 60))
        segments_list.append(image)

        if len(segments_list) == 8:
            seg1 = Input(shape=segments_list[0].shape, name="seg1")
            input_list.append(seg1)
            conv0_1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(seg1)
            act0_1 = Activation("relu")(conv0_1)
            batch0_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(act0_1)
            pool0_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch0_1)
            drop0_1 = Dropout(0.25)(pool0_1)

            conv0_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same")(drop0_1)
            act0_2 = Activation("relu")(conv0_2)
            batch0_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(act0_2)
            pool0_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch0_2)
            drop0_2 = Dropout(0.25)(pool0_2)
            out1 = Flatten()(drop0_2)
            output_list.append(out1)

# the same design until model 8
.
.
.
            seg8 = Input(shape=segments_list[7].shape, name="seg8")
            input_list.append(seg8)
            conv7_1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(seg8)
            act7_1 = Activation("relu")(conv7_1)
            batch7_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(act7_1)
            pool7_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch7_1)
            drop7_1 = Dropout(0.25)(pool7_1)

            conv7_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same")(drop7_1)
            act7_2 = Activation("relu")(conv7_2)
            batch7_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(act7_2)
            pool7_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch7_2)
            drop7_2 = Dropout(0.25)(pool7_2)
            out8 = Flatten()(drop7_2)
            output_list.append(out8)
# -----------Now Concatenation of 8 models will be start-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            merge = Concatenate()(output_list)
            print("Concatenation Ended...Dense will be done...")
            den1 = Dense(128)(merge)
            act = Activation("relu")(den1)
            bat = BatchNormalization()(act)
            drop = Dropout(0.5)(bat)

            model_out.append(drop)

        else:
            continue

        small_model = Model(inputs=input_list, outputs=model_out)
        model_list.append(small_model)
        print("Concatenation done")
        segments_list = []
        input_list = []
        output_list = []
        model_out = []
# it is OK till here, after this step I don't know how can I concatenate the output of each concatenated result

den2 = Dense(128)(model_list) # the error in this line
act2 = Activation("relu")(den2)
bat2 = BatchNormalization()(act2)
drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(bat2)

# softmax classifier
print("Classification will be start")
final_out1 = Dense(classes)(drop2)
final_out = Activation('softmax')(final_out1)
#inp = Input(shape=den2.shape)
#big_model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=final_out)
final_out.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
final_out.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),validation_data=(testX, testY),steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

When I run the program, it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer dense_66 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
```

Can anyone please help me. How can I concatenate, compile, train the all dataset. any hint may be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing a list of model objects `model_list` which are not tensors, they wrap computation graphs that given inputs produce tensors. Instead you should collect the tensor outputs, something along the lines of:

```
  #...
  model_ins.append(seg1)
  # ...
  model_outs.append(drop)
# ...
all_model_outs = Concatenate(model_outs)
flat_model_outs = Flatten()(all_model_outs)
den2 = Dense(128)(flat_model_outs) # the error in this line
# ...
big_model= Model(model_ins, final_out)
big_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
big_model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),validation_data=(testX, testY),steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

The idea is you can take any input and output computation of a larger graph and convert to a model to train it. Here, the big model is all the inputs to the final output you compute that will train all the smaller models together. You can still use the smaller models to predict individually later.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you mean the big model contains the all inputs of all dataset? yes I do what you propose but with the small model(concatenate each 8 models), but I'm confused how can I concatenate the output of all of the dataset (the output of all N and M inside folders).

Comment: What you propose is concatenation of small model and it is inside the loop, I was combine the all inputs and outputs in a list and place them in a big_model such as:  all_ins.append(model_ins), all_outs.append(model_outs) and concatenate(all_outs) i.e(make big_model input all dataset input and output all dataset output) but I also get the following error:Layer concatenate_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. I wish my idea is clear. Can you please help me?